# How can I store a list of C-like structures in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let me explain the problem by a simple example:

Let's say I want to store 100 people's name, and brand(s) of the car(s) they own (so there can be 1 or more).

I was thinking about using dictionary in Python, but is can only store 1 string attached to one name. Perhaps I can seperate the cars' names like this:

```
people_and_cars = {'Jack':'Opel Audi'}
```

and when I need them, I can seperate it into 'Opel' and 'Audi by the split() function, but it seems a bit silly solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just store a list of strings as the value of the dict?  `{'Jack': ['Opel', 'Audi']}`

Comment: What do you mean by C-like structures? Like structs?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your data in a dictionary:

```
people_and_cars = {}
```

Jack has an Opel car, but he might buy another one later, so I store this one in a list like this:

```
people_and_cars['Jack'] = ['Opel']

print(people_and_cars)  # Output: {'Jack': ['Opel']}
```

Now, Jack buys a new Audi car, so I add it as follows:

```
people_and_cars['Jack'].append('Audi')

print(people_and_cars)  # Output: {'Jack': ['Opel', 'Audi']}
```

You may need to check first whether a person exists in your dictionary or not, you can do that like below:

```
if person in people_and_cars:
    people_and_cars[person].append(car)
else:
    people_and_cars[person] = [car]
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the list of the cars for each person as a list. The list will be then the values of the keys (people) in your dictionary.

For your example:

```
people_and_cars = dict()
people_and_cars['Jack'] = ["Opel", "Audi"]
```